# c# databases for wp7, pc and xbox

Tags: c#, sql, database, windows, portability

I am currently working on a game in c# that I want to put on the market for windows 7, windows phone mango, and Xbox 360. Which SQL package will be portable across all 3 platforms for a database that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is almost definitely your best bet if you want the same database backend over all three platforms. There is a port of it for [windows phone 7](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx), there is a really good .NET library for windows, and apparently is no problem [on XNA](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11159/xna-with-sqlite).

The only one of those three platforms I've used it extensively on is windows 7, and it's been really good.

The only thing I'd add is that while I think SQLite is a good choice for all three platforms, there is no need to have the same backend, the actual choice of back end is pretty easily abstracted away.

Comment: Thanks, I have very limited  knowledge and experience with databases, but the abstraction seems to make sense to me, since I only need to pass query and statement strings to and from the database.

Comment: I have only ever used SQL in netbeans (derby) working with Java... What are the differences between SQLite and the SQL I used in Netbeans with Java?

Comment: I have never used derby, but looks like there is a comparison on the SQLite page http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteVersusDerby. Good luck with what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

CoolStorage is a cross-platform database library supporting a number of database backends (including SQLite). The Windows Phone version supports (only) SQLite in isolated storage, but when you compile the source code, I bet it also works perfectly on Xbox (using SQLite).

This is the link: http://viciproject.com/coolstorage

Comment: Sounds cool! (you might what to mention you're the founder of the vici project though :) )

Comment: I will definitely be checking it out next time I write something for windows phone

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/4cbf20d6-fc36-437b-aac2-b505206ab7f5/), there is no database support for Windows Phone 7.

You can probably use SQLite (the norm for Android). Apparently there are several possibilities of running that on Windows Phone 7. Do a Google search for `sqlite Windows Phone`.