# XNA Windows Game simple database access - .mdb does not work [very basic]

Tags: sql, database, windows, ms-access, xna

I'm working on a game project for a class and we could pick between XNA and Java. The teams who chose to use XNA are in the minority and a lot of the lectures centred on Java content - one of the main theory themes in the lectures however is that we use databases for accessing data, but this is covered in theory only for a variety of software engineering implementation options, not actually practical implementation for XNA.

So we've made our game and now want to include a database - however I'm finding out the hard way XNA isn't happy with .mdb or .msaccess files? Especially as I'm constantly getting things like this:

"Cannot autodetect which importer to use for "Test.mdb". There are no importers which handle this file type. Specify the importer that handles this file type in your project."

Which has left me completely stuck - a lot of the online solutions are suggesting using a SQL Server Database but I wouldn't even know how to go about creating one of those from a really basic level - also there are 5 of us working on this game and getting everyone to successfully install SQL Server without a hitch in the time we have left isn't the most realistic option.

Are there any other XNA non-server based database options? If not, what would be the best way to go about implementing a SQL server database into our game that five different people can run flawlessly who might all have different pre-installed existing SQL Server versions? Would that even matter? I say this because it caused a fair bit of carnage in an ASP.NET class.

Thanks in advance, really have no clue when it comes to databases beyond Access, thought it would be a matter of "using System.Data.OleDb;", importing a file, and setting up a connection string.

EDIT: By going through Data > Add new data source, and following the instructions, I have been able to try to add both MSACCESS and SQL Compact databases! Woohoo, one step closer. However I am always getting a "Could not get type information for .dataset" error :/ Th good thing is at least a NameDataSet.xsd file is generated - how can this be used with query strings? Do I need to manually type a connection string? There isn't a lot for starting with no prior knowledge :(

Comment: Could you give us an example of a query you'll be making against this putative database?  At the moment, it sounds as if all you need are arrays.

Comment: We used arrays for a variety of co-ordinates in our last game an it was horrible, never again! We have 40+ description strings, 100+ sets of co-ordinates, player deails, and the like. I don't specifically know how I am going to query them yet.

I would just like to know how to incorporate a database into XNA, I know arrays are easier but we don't want to take the easy way out. I've seen other posts about XNA and SQL Databases and they really do not seem that hard to set up, I just can't find an XNA-specific guide for a database beginner, and the "importer" error is really hindering me :)

Comment: Arrays aren't just easier, they're also (usually) more efficient; that is, both faster and less demanding on the system.  Better, in other words.  Of course, if the class is about databases that's a different story.  It's hardly unusual for a teaching exercise to take a less practical approach for pedagogical reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Using access in this manner is a bad idea really, it's rather outdated and has a number of problems with modern designs, unicode and working on 64bit OS's for example.

SQL server isn't a good idea either, its just the wrong tool for the job and you'd have to consider getting a License for everyone using your code.

At this point I'd suggest that you consider looking at an in-process database such as SqlLite or Firebird; but what I think would be a more relevant thing at the moment is to ask what you want the database to actually do ?

If you're purely using it to store config data for your game, then it's massive overkill.

Lastly, this isn't an XNA problem as such - if a database can be used in .Net then it will work.

Comment: referring to access, the problems are generally to do with older databases that need the JET Oledb connector...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response!

It's to store a number of co-ordinates for board squares and details of different players (only one player at a time can go and it's turn-based, we were told mutli-player would be overkill), and also descriptions of squares and other long-text strings within the game. A player table was our main aim.

I wasn't aware of in-process databases but I don't mind using Access if the problems aren't _too_ detrimental as we've already a nice .msaccess file ready. I've made XNA games before I just haven't touched databases since the days of GCSE ICT Coursework!

Comment: What about state; are player details required to be kept around after the app closes are are they only relevant when the game is running ? I'm just trying to identify if you need permanent storage or not as the level config could easily be stored in a binary serialised file or even an XML file for that matter.

Comment: Just when the game is running. I've seen a few options saying XML, however I think a database might get us some extra marks as it's a tad more complicated - then again I don't want to lose marks for overcomplicating either haha!

Comment: Database is such an overkill that it is more likely to get you a lower grade. Like when a classmate of mine thought it would be a good idea to use Oracle for a (VERY) simple mp3 catalog system. He almost failed the course only because of that hahaha

Comment: Is it possible then to use an XML file to import data for entire classes then? Like a player class and all the variables within. This would have been incredibly easy if "using System.Data.OleDb" worked and the .msaccess file didn't throw an "Cannot autodetect which importer to use for "Test.mdb" error. The only problem is we've already made a database populated with quite a few things so this is going to be quite a waste of time :(

Comment: You can use LINQ to XML - i think since you already have your data, it would be a perfect solution. LINQ allows you to perform queries on sets of data in a similar way to SQL.

Comment: as for importing data for entire class from XML, that is what content pipeline is for. If you have your data in .xml, you can add it to your content project, then load it in your game.

Comment: My main concern still is that the module demonstrator has been pushing database use, I tried using an SQL one an still get "Cannot autodetect which importer to use for "MyDatabase#1.sdf". There are no importers which handle this file type."

I wouldn't mind using XML I just feel I haven't properly tackled this yet before giving up and my team have their heart set on this database. I don't want to just abandon it because there's an easier option :) I guess based on solutions I've read you -can- use a database, I just need to sort out the "importer" error. I'll look into the LINQ XML queries now

Comment: What I'm wondering is if I'm going the wrong way about it by adding the database directly to the content alongside trying to set up a connection in the server explorer? This guy here has pulled it off for example but obv doesn't explain how as my problem is very basic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728306/c-sharp-databases-for-wp7-pc-and-xbox

I am grateful for the useful XML responses, so please don't think I am dismissing them, I just think even attempting to get a SQL DB working would be good experience for me :)

Comment: "Cannot detect which importer to use" is because you're trying to add it to Content project. Did you try adding it to your game project? Also, send an email and ask if you would get more or less points for using a database, then decide.